# Bulk Move All Mails From An Outlook Folder To Another Folder

Tags: vba, outlook

Can I move all the mails (that category is blank) from an Outlook folder to another Outlook folder at once like copy and paste not through loop, move bulk mails at once?

Like if we do manually, apply filter, select those mails and drag to another folder.

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide any method for moving items in bulk. The best what you could do is to apply a search criteria to find only items that should be moved and call the [Move](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.move) method to each of them programmatically in the loop. Read more about possible ways of filtering items in Outlook programmatically (searching):

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)
- [Advanced search in Outlook programmatically: C#, VB.NET](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2012/05/31/outlook-search-csharp-vbnet/)

Answer (score 0):

As Eugene mentioned, there is no way to do that in Outlook Object Model. If using [Redemption](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption) is an option (I am its author), you can call [RDOFolder](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOFolder.htm).[Items](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOItems.htm).`MoveMultiple` and pass an array of entry ids as a parameter. The array of entry ids can be constructed by calling `RDOFolder.Items.MAPITable.`[ExecSQL](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/mapitable.htm#ExecSQL) with the appropriate restriction ([ExecSQL](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/mapitable.htm#ExecSQL) will return an instance of the [ADODB.Recordset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/recordset-object-ado?view=sql-server-ver15) object).

Answer (score 0):

1. Create folder outside Inbox.
2. Then I created a rule like shown in screenshot.
3. Tick Checkbox to run it now and save.

It will take sometime depend upon the inbox size to complete.
Good luck!!!

[image: Move All from Inbox to folder]